# Update Image Position

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS. I am trying to draw image at particular position. I am using NSMutableArray for storing its position.

```
// I am calling addCutter method in init method of ViewController
- (void) addCutter 
{
     //gameModel.cutters is NSMutable Array for position
      [gameModel.cutters addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:gameModel.cutterRect]];

      cutter = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cutter.png"]];

      //cutter is UIImageView
      [cutter setFrame:[[gameModel.cutters objectAtIndex:[gameModel.cutters count]-1] CGRectValue]];

      cutter.tag = [cutters count] + 100;

      [cutters addObject:cutter];

      [self.view addSubview:[cutters objectAtIndex:([cutters count]-1)]];

}
```

but Image is not update its position

```
//code for update the position

-(void) moveCutter 
{
     for(int i=0;i<[gameModel.cutters count]-1;i++) 
     {
          CGRect newCutterRect = [[gameModel.cuttersobjectAtIndex:i] CGRectValue];

          newCutterRect.origin.x += [[disX objectAtIndex:i]floatValue];
          newCutterRect.origin.y += [[disY objectAtIndex:i]floatValue];

          [gameModel.cutters replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:newCutterRect]];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually set the new frame for the view. You just changed a copy of the view's original frame, which has no connection anymore to the view.

Comment: how to set new frame for the view

Answer (score 0):

You need to update frame as well:

```
-(void) moveCutter 
 {

    for (cutter in cutters) {
        [cutter removeFromSuperview];
   }
   for(int i=0;i<[gameModel.cutters count]-1;i++) 
   {
        CGRect newCutterRect = [[gameModel.cutters objectAtIndex:i] CGRectValue];
        newCutterRect.origin.x += [[disX objectAtIndex:i]floatValue];
        newCutterRect.origin.y += [[disY objectAtIndex:i]floatValue];
        cutter = [cutters objectAtIndex:i];//Get your object here as well
        cutter.frame = newCutterRect; // Update frame here
       [self.view addSubview:cutter];
        [gameModel.cutters replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:newCutterRect]];
     }
  }
```

Comment: @user2546410 what is the issues with this, code you are getting?

Comment: I have put the above code in my project but image position is not changing

Comment: Try to debug it, And see newCutterRect frame. If newCutterRect have other frame, surely youe image position will change.

Comment: ya, newCutterRect frame is changing but imge position is not changing